# Does the operator $(\hat{f}\cdot m )^\vee$ maps Schwartz in it self?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Given $m \in L^\infty$ and $\phi \in \mathcal{S}$ a Schwartz function, is it true that $(\hat{f}\cdot m)^\vee$ is a Schwartz function??

I trying to prove this so I could conclude that operator of the form $(\hat{f}\cdot m)^\vee$  maps $\mathcal{S}$ to it self.

*Attempt:* Given $\alpha, \beta$ multi-index, we have to prove that
$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R^n}}|x^\alpha\partial^\beta(\hat{f}\cdot m)^\vee(x)| < \infty. $$

When $\alpha = 0$, using some properties of Fourier tranform, we get
$$\partial^\beta(\hat{f}\cdot m)^\vee(x) = ((2\pi i \xi)^\beta\hat{f}(\xi)m(\xi))^\vee(x) = ((\partial^\beta f)^\wedge\cdot m)^\vee(x).$$
Then, taking the absolute value of the expression above and by definition of inverse Fourier transform,
\begin{align*}
|\partial^\beta(\hat{f}\cdot m)^\vee(x)| = &
\left| \int_\mathbb{R^n} (\partial^\beta f)^\wedge(\xi)m(\xi) e^{2\pi i \xi\cdot x} d\xi  \right| \\
\leq & \int_\mathbb{R^n} |(\partial^\beta f)^\wedge(\xi)||m(\xi)|d\xi \\
\leq &\|m\|_{L^\infty} \int_\mathbb{R^n} |(\partial^\beta f)^\wedge(\xi)|d\xi  \\
=& \|m\|_{L^\infty} \|(\partial^\beta f)^\wedge\|_{L^1}.
\end{align*}
The $L^1$-norm of $(\partial^\beta f)^\wedge$ is finite, since this is a Schwartz function.

My problem is for $\alpha \neq 0$. For simplicity and in view of properties of Fourier transform, I changed $x^\alpha$ for $(-2\pi i x)^\alpha$ and I want to show that the supreme of $|(-2\pi i x)^\alpha \partial^\beta(\hat{f}\cdot m)^\vee(x)|$ over all $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$ is finite:

\begin{align*}
|(-2\pi i x)^\alpha \partial^\beta(\hat{f}\cdot m)^\vee(x)| =  & |(-2\pi i x)^\alpha ((\partial^\beta f)^\wedge\cdot m)^\vee(x)| \\
= & |[\partial^\alpha((\partial^\beta f)^\wedge \cdot m)]^\vee(x)|.
\end{align*}

How do I proceed from here?? Does it make sense the derivative $\partial^\alpha((\partial^\beta f)^\wedge \cdot m)$ ??

Comment: Since the Fourier transform maps $\mathcal{S}$ to itself it suffices to check if $m(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)$ is Schwartz. But if $m$ is in $L^\infty$ and not $C^\infty$ then $m \hat{f}$ might not be smooth, so might not be Schwartz.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Thanks! This question just came up to me because I'm studying the Hilbert transform and I wanted to know that the Hilbert transform maps Schwartz in it self. But looks like I only have that the Hilbert transform maps Schwartz in L^2...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(\hat{f} \cdot m )^\vee$ is Schwarz, then so is $\hat{f}\cdot m$ (as the Fourier transform sends Schwarz space into itself). However, $\hat{f} \cdot m$ needs not even to be continuous (as we only assume $m\in L^\infty$).

So, no. The function $(\hat{f} \cdot m)^\vee$ needs not to be Schwarz.

Comment: That's it!. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome :)